# Skeptics.SE and Fitness.SE are missing the Quorum and Convention badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, private-beta

At first, I assumed that it was because they were in private beta but, now that [Skeptics.SE is in public beta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111/whats-the-process-on-public-beta/120#120), they are still missing on both sites. No other badge seems to be missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These badges were missed in one of our database migration scripts - this will be fixed during the next deploy.