# Beta badge: How actively do you need to participate in a private beta to receive it?

Tags: discussion, private-beta, beta-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

I had 2 answers, 0 questions, and did not get this badge on [skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/), but looking around the badge list, I see one user with 3 questions and 0 answers that got the badge, as well as a user with 3 answers/0 questions, and a user with 1 question/2 answers.

So as far as I can tell, the minimum cutoff seems to be 3 total posts (questions and/or answers).

Can anyone confirm this? Is it an absolute number, or does it adjust to the exchange's overall activity? And are there any other criterion?

**Edit:** Herp, I did not find [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71879/what-are-the-requirements-of-beta-badges-on-se-sites) when I searched about this before asking my question.

Comment: I voted to close too hastily on this one; if you vote to close as a dupe of anything, use [the post the OP found](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71879/what-are-the-requirements-of-beta-badges-on-se-sites)

Comment: @Pop If the criteria aren't in the big FAQ, they should be added. I was going to link to Chris' answer from there, but he didn't seem too confident about the criteria.

Comment: @Jon: I think the criteria in the FAQs for this badge are wrong.  Jeff said somewhere that they changed, but never said to what.

Answer (score 3):

> #### Beta
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Participate actively in a site's private beta phase
>
>   - Active participation means earning at least three bronze badges
> - Not awarded on Meta sites, including Meta Stack Overflow
> - Source: [Jeff's comment to his own answer to "Why are beta badges awarded at all?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/why-are-beta-badges-awarded-at-all/#comment-44251)

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67399#67399

Comment: This doesn't seem to correlate with my data-- I had 9 bronze badges.

Comment: Aye, one of the [Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/117/ron) has Beta but only 1 bronze badge, anyway.

Comment: Hm... this has been accurate for the few betas I participated in. Skeptics has been out of private beta for merely one day, at this point; the Beta badge has been known to take a little while to show up. Not sure what to think about Grace Note's comment; [two badges were not being displayed on Skeptics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81718/skeptics-se-and-fitness-se-are-missing-the-quorum-and-convention-badges) for a while, but one was silver.

Comment: It seems this was changed in July '10 or so-- see the last three comments to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/should-the-beta-badges-stop-being-awarded-to-users/19#19).