# When do I earn the Beta badge

Tags: support, beta-phase, private-beta, beta-badge

On the Fitness beta site I have at the momment 8 broze badges and I was wondering when do we get the silver beta badge. Will it be in the private beta, during public beta, or when it is live?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will get the beta badge once the site moves into public beta,assuming you meet the [qualifying requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81727/beta-badge-how-actively-do-you-need-to-participate-in-a-private-beta-to-receive/81728#81728)

> #### Beta
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Participate actively in a site's private beta phase
>
>   - Not just 3 bronze badges anymore, but the exact requirements not disclosed to prevent users from just doing the bare minimum.
> - Not awarded on Meta sites, including Meta Stack Overflow
> - Source: [Jeff's comment to his own answer to "Why are beta badges awarded at all?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/why-are-beta-badges-awarded-at-all/#comment-44251)

The "exact requirements" seem to have something to do with posting answers/questions and getting upvotes for them.

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67399#67399

Comment: I forget where, but I think Jeff said this has changed and it is now harder to get the Beta badge.  I don't think he said what the new requirements are, but I suspect they include at least one answer.  When Graphic Design left private beta, I had 5 bronze badges, one question, >50 votes(given by me), and did not get the beta badge.

Comment: [Source(In the comments)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/should-the-beta-badges-stop-being-awarded-to-users/19#19): @mmyers no, the requirements are a bit more strict now. – Jeff Atwood♦ Jul 23 '10 at 18:55

Comment: A bit more strict? I don't understand. I had [twelve bronze badges](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/72/nikai) in bitcoin after the private beta and didn't get this badge, others had only two but received it.